# How to remove the list of actions in Grid Customer magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to remove those options in the list up the grid [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove this actions you need to override **customer_listing** and remove from it.

Copy it to your custom theme and than change it as per your need.

Eg.

> Vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/view/adminhtml/layout/ui_component/customer_listing.xml
>
> `Don't forget to clear cache after override file.`

Comment: i created a new module and i commented  this part but no result

Comment: Where did you create XML file. Paste file path here.

Comment: @DevelopperMagento, are you sure that your module is overriding UI XML correctly?

Comment: @DevelopperMagento, You dont need to create module for this Use my answer It's working for me.

Comment: thanks for your replay brother can i ask you some questions

Comment: @DevelopperMagento, If it helps give it up vote to help others. Its Magento Community you can ask question. If its different subject I recommend you to ask new one. I'll try to help you.